# Information bubbles

Tags: interaction-design

I am talking about the little (i) icons next to phrases in forms, etc., that describe an item in detail. How to you trigger the display of such bubbles? 
Intuitively, when I see an (i) next to a phrase, I want to click to see its contents (click-to-see something is what I am used to on the web). I get a bit of a surprise if I roll over an (i) and see it pop open right away, this momentarily breaks my flow. I also like to be able to click anywhere inside the bubble to hide it.

How to do you trigger the display of info bubbles, and why?

Comment: Are you asking how from an implementation stance or do you mean from an interaction design/affordance point of view?

Comment: From interaction design stand point!

Comment: What type of product is this for? Mobile app, website, web app, computer program, game ?

Comment: it's an online store! (but really my question applies to any website - responsive site.)

Answer (score 1):

This is a classic question and one that will inevitably divide opinion. I've changed my own.

Roll-over/on-hover "tooltip" interactions are useful in that they require no additional motor effort and can contain fully complex html and media for the user to interact with and learn from before moving their pointer off the layer, and it disappears.  Great.  But if you position these on the pointer's "flight path" across your features their indiscriminate triggering can be distracting: some "tooltips" can take up much of the screen.

On-click/active triggers prevent the indiscriminate triggering of "tooltips" and afford the user a choice on whether to review the "tooltip" content, or not.  It's on offer and requires a positive interaction. The content can then disappear on loss of focus, or on a positive (on-click/press) Close action.

Device wise, it seems that on most tablet and phone browsers on-hover CSS "tooltips" will only display on-press even if on-hover is designed.

I was until only recently an on-hover champion; but the advent of multi-device design has me dancing on the side of on-click/ on-press with a Close button.  If some touch-screen users cannot access on-hover triggers without pressing, then perhaps all users should share the experience across displays and user groups?

If using on-hover then for the sake of accessibility - and depending on how you call your dynamic content - don't forget offer skip-links for accessibility purposes; not all users  want to hover on an "i" when they see it; similarly not all users who won't see it want to hear it's content.

Comment: Sharing the experience across devices is what I am about too! Good point.